# Could not connect to Gmail SMTP host

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am getting issue while sending email using Gmail email SMTP port and JakartaMail.

Code:

```
final String email = "xxxx@xxx.com";
final String pass = "xxxxx";
  
public Email() {
    this.callerObj = this;
    this.msg = null;
    this.mp = null;
    this.props = null;
    this.session = null;
    this.props = new Properties();
    this.props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
    this.props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
    this.props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); 
    this.props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
    this.props.setProperty("mail.debug", rbApp.getString("app.mail.debug"));
    this.session = Session.getInstance(this.props, null);
}

.....

session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(email, pass);
    }
});
....
```

Error message:

> MessagingException caught >> Fail to send Email >> Could not connect
> to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1

Here is my SMTP server configuration in Thunderbird:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7kSQ.png)

Comment: These days, you'll almost certainly need either OAuth or an application token to connect to GMail, in addition to what you're already doing. GMail is something of a moving target, so you'll need to look into its current auth requirements.

Comment: Your question seems to have nothing to do with Thunderbird, which is an email client, while your coding a Java program to connect to Gmail. And if you get an exception, post the full exception stacktrace, not just its message.

Comment: Absolutely right. But since Thunderbird has been mentioned, it illustrates my point perfectly. Even Thunderbird, given a complete set of correct credentials and configurations, requires *additional* authorization when you first connect a GMail account to it, and will ask for it.

Comment: Try port 587 instead of port 465. (A guess based on `starttls` and SMTP knowledge withou jakarta knowledge).

Comment: Hi @AnFi, I have changed the port to 587. Successfully connected to the Gmail SMTP host and sent the email. Thank you very much, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try port 587 instead of port 465. (A guess based on starttls and SMTP knowledge without jakarta knowledge).

`starttls` suggests support for `STARTTLS` smtp command which means port 587 (or 25).
Port 465 is for smtps - encryption is started before any SMTP level communication.